# Connecting Tally ERP 9 real time data with Excel workbook

Tags: excel, odbc, tally

I want to connect my client's live Tally ERP 9 data with Excel in order to make some reports. My purpose is fetch the real time accounting data into Excel. I have tried connecting Excel to Tally through ODBC Connection but I am unable to find the data of Transactions from the given data tables. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Using Tally Definition Language you can create your own data source (Collection), and expose it in odbc connection

```
[Collection : ODBCTrans]
    Type        : Voucher
    IsOdbcTable : Yes
    Fetch       : Date, VoucherTypeName, Amount
```

Copy paste above code in a text file and attach it with tally erp, to know steps follow below links:

https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/DeveloperReference/td9/working_with_projects/load_tcp_file.htm

After this file is loaded successfully with tally, when you connect to odbc you will find a new table with name "ODBCTrans"

for more details about creating collections follow below link
https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/DeveloperReference/tdlreference/objects_and_collections.htm#collectioncapabilities